# Netsuite RMA sample reference

Tags: netsuite

I hope below question is very generic but seeking some expert advice to work on RMA process.

Generation of new sales order for replacements & refunding the customer the specified amount, generating item receipt to track items being returned prior to refunding customer.
eg:
Looking for sample suite script reference to refund back to customer's credit card $XXX (product amount paid + original shipping) for a given sales order.

-Bhasker

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into SuiteScript 1.0's `nlapiTransformRecord` or SuiteScript 2.0's `N/record/transform`. You should be able to transform a Sales Order into a Return Authorization with this API.

If you can give quite a bit more detail about what type of script you're looking for, what triggers you'd like to be able to use to set off this script, I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Is there a available user event script reference for say -customer relationship will fill out the RMA form and generate return labels, but generation of new sales order for replacements  refunding the customer the specified amount should be automated using scripting.